# How do I make <a href> link to open in a new tab but in an iFrame part of another template?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I have created a Django web app which throws document recommendation to users based on their search query; the next thing I am trying to achieve is to able to make users open these recommended documents in a new tab but in an iFrame which would part of another template.

Also, I just want to use HTML and Python to achieve this result.

Till now, I am just able to open the documents in a new tab which is not part of my Django framework

```
<html>

<body>

{% for document in Documents %}
<a href = "{link to the corresponding document on my system}"
target = "_blank">
<p><font color = "blue"><b>{{ document }}</b></font></p>
</a>
{% endfor %}

</body>

</html>
```

The above code loops through the list of recommended documents generated by model and prints their hyperlinked names on an HTML page. These links just open the document in a new tab but I want them to open in an iFrame on a new template which is part of my Django framework.

Comment: pseudo codes are not clear enough, please share more on the new template's view, url, html, also how `link to the corresponding document on my system` is generated?

Comment: Maybe `href` should point to "another view" with document URL as a parameter.